# Gradle: Multiproject build - How to determine projects that need a rebuild?

Tags: java, gradle

I have a multi project build setup. If I execute the "jar" task of any subproject, gradle checks whether it needs to rebuild a certain dependent project or not by using the org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.

Is there a way to access this information to like build a custom task or a task in a custom plugin which automatically copies the jars of theses projects to somewhere?

Comment: If you have declared proper inputs and outputs of your custom task, gradle should take care of re-building the required projects automatically.

Comment: I know that's what it's doing but I want to retrieve a list of projects which changed and did a rebuild to copy the jars to somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `jar.didWork` to determine whether the task `jar` actually did some work or not if I remember correctly: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#getDidWork()

Or maybe more appropriate, use something like the following:

```
gradle.taskGraph.afterTask { task, state ->
    // check anything on Task or TaskState, like didWork, executed, failure, noSource, skipMessage, skipped or upToDate
}
```